# How to synchronize audio and video when using x11grab and pulse?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMpeg to grab the desktop using `x11grab`. I am also using pulse for audio. However, in my FFMpeg output, the audio is ahead of the video. My arguments are:

```
ffmpeg \
      -hide_banner \
      -loglevel error \
      -f x11grab \
      -framerate 30 \
      -draw_mouse 0 \
      -video_size <width>x<height> \
      -thread_queue_size 1024 \
      -i :0.0+0,0 \
      -f pulse \
      -ac 2 \
      -thread_queue_size 1024 \
      -i <pulse device name> \
      -map 0:v:0 \
      -c:v libx264 \
      -preset ultrafast \
      -minrate:v 500K \ 
      -maxrate:v 4M \
      -bufsize:v 4M \
      -x264-params keyint=90 \
      -pix_fmt yuv420p \
      -map 1:a:0 \
      -c:a aac \
      -ab 128k \
      -ac 2 \
      -ar 44100 \
      -f flv \
      <rtmp url>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `-copyts` in the **output** parameters. So my output now looks like

```
-copyts \
-f flv \
<rtmp url>
```